# Error while fetching data from Core Data

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I’m working on an dictionary app. this app using core data and I'm very new to core data. In the database, records stored with a single entity called **dictionary** and **dictionary** entity has just two attributes “**English**” & “**Meaning**”.
So whenever user types some char say a, in `UISearchBar`, I want to fetch records from data base that starts from “a”, if user types data a than b that I want to fetch records starts from “ab” and so on.

I’m trying same thing by below code:

```
// Fetch the devices from persistent data store

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:ENTITY_NAME inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];
// retrive the objects with a given value for a certain property
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K beginswith[c] %@",@"English",searchText];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

// Edit the sort key as appropriate.
/*NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"English" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];*/

// Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
// nil for section name key path means "no sections".
/*NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;*/

NSError *error = nil;
_searchResult = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

when this code executes my app crashes with the following error msg:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath English not found in entity <NSSQLEntity TamilEnglishDict id=1>'
```

**EDIT:**

this is how my Data Model is...

[image: Data Model]

Any who can guide me to the right path of fetching records properly?

Comment: Can you say something about the model? In your entity there is no attribute `English`.

Comment: @flexaddicted attribute "English" is there. 
As far as my model is concern I try to explain it..
I had some xml files, I parse those files and created a data base.
Directly in the managedObject I setValue with two key "English" and "Meaning". that's how I created database and fetching records the way I explained in my question.

Comment: Show me the model. What is `ENTITY_NAME`? Provide a screenshot if possible.

Comment: Is `ENTITY_NAME` the same as **dictionary** in your question?

Comment: I would like to see the model, if possible.

Comment: Other detail: Is `ENTITY_NAME` the same as **dictionary** and they are equal to `TamilEnglishDict`?

Comment: if I add a screenshot of sqliteManager, will it we enough for you?
yes actually TamilEnglishDict is the entity name but I was hit & trying so I changed it.

Comment: Yes. Try also to remove the app from the simulator and run it again.

Comment: I uploaded my question @flexaddicted please check it

Comment: Show me the model created through Xcode. Not the store.

Comment: I haven't created any model class neither while creating database from XML files nor on the time of fetching it, I simple using NSManagedObject to do that.

Comment: Yes. But you said *yes actually TamilEnglishDict is the entity name but I was hit & trying so I changed it*. So what's the name of your new entity? Also try to remove the app from the simulator and run it again.

Comment: TamilEnglishDict entity is there in .xcdatamodeld file I haven't created any class for this entity.

Comment: So haven't created no model in Xcode? With model I mean http://cdn4.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/FailedBanksModel1.jpg. **TRY ALSO TO REMOVE THE APP FROM THE SIMULATOR AND RUN IT AGAIN**

Comment: I have tried removing app from simulator but no luck.

Comment: I updated data model please have a look

Comment: how about @"english" instead of @"English"? I believe it's case sensitive.

Comment: Yes it works...but while saving those values in managedObject I wrote 
'[managedObject setValue:[obj objectForKey:@"English"] forKey:@"English"]';
The key was "English" not "english" than how can it accessible with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's case sensitive.

So the correct predicate is the following.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K beginswith[c] %@",@"english", searchText];
```

or just

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"english beginswith[c] %@", searchText];
```

> but while saving those values in managedObject I wrote '[managedObject
>   setValue:[obj objectForKey:@"English"] forKey:@"English"]';

So now edit your question and explain me the comment above. What do you mean?

Maybe you could just do

```
[managedObject setValue:[obj objectForKey:@"English"] forKey:@"english"];
```

Comment: thanks for bearing with me so patiently. 
While I was creating database from XML files that is how I stored data in managedObject and save the context.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma  Do you have any other problems? If not, please mark the answer as correct. Cheers.

Comment: I'll do it for sure because it is indeed a correct ans. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code & your code is correct, you just have to change Predicate you are using. just replace this code with your predicate & hope your problem is solve. because you want result that conatain "ab" or "a" or "b" so you have to use "contain" in place of "beginswith".

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@",@"English", searchText];
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: I used contains as well but it doest work at all.
when I use contains, my app crashes with error

 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (English CONTAINS[cd] "w")'

Comment: English will be your column name & search text will be your search string

Comment: Why changing from `BEGINSWITH` to `CONTAINS` will resolve the problem? That's not true. In addition `CONTAINS` is more expensive than the first.